# Can const-default-constructible objects be of non-class types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Per my understanding, for class type `T` to be [const-default-constructible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#7) type, the default-initialization of `T` shall invoke a user-provided constructor, or `T` shall provide a default member initializer for each non-variant non-static data member: ([[dcl.init]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#7))

> **A class type `T`** is *const-default-constructible* if
> default-initialization of `T` would invoke a user-provided constructor
> of `T` (not inherited from a base class) or if
>
> - (7.4) each direct
>   non-variant non-static data member `M` of `T` has a default member
>   initializer [..]

Noting the **bold** part, it seems to me that const-default-constructible types can only be class types (including unions and structs). Therefore I can't say that `const int`, for example, is const-default-constructible type since `int` is not a class type.

You might ask, from where this confusion comes. Basically, [class.default.ctor]/2 says:

> A defaulted default constructor for class `X` is defined as deleted
> if:
>
> - [..]
> - (2.4) **any** non-variant non-static data member of *const-qualified* type (or array thereof) with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* is not
>   ***const-default-constructible*** ([dcl.init]),
> - [..]

Notice the word "**any**". This bullet considers cases where `X` has data member `M`, and `M` is of class types as well as non-class types. But per [[dcl.init]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#7), the const-default-constructible types are limited to only be class types.

Consider the following example,

```
struct S
{
    const int I;
    // Is the type of S::I said to be non-const-default-constructible?

    S() = default;
};
```

Is there missing wording? Am I misreading the quotes?

---

PS: Thanks to @463035818_is_not_a_number for clarifying this. Consider this case:

```
struct X
{
    const int M = 0;
    // Is the type of X::M said to be const-default-constructible?

    X() = default;
};
```

Comment: you know that `S() = default;` has not much effect? `S`s default constructor is deleted. I am not a language lawyer and reading the sections you quote makes me dizzy, but it seems to be consistent

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. I'm just copy-past from the code I testing. I added it Just to prevent `S` from being an aggregate.

Comment: hm? `S` is not default constructible, the defaulted default constructor is not created I suppose because `const int` is not const-default-constructible. What do you miss from the wording? Why do you think you misread it?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number _"Why do you think you misread it?"_ because `int` itself is non-class type

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - Consider a case where X has data member M and M is of class type. Per the given quotes you can say that M is const-default-constructible or non-const-default-constructible.  But my confusion arises in a case where M is of non-class type

Comment: yes `int` is non-class type, hence it is not const-default-constructible, hence the default constructor is not created. I am not claiming it would be obvious, just trying to understand what you miss from the wording

Comment: when it says "A `X` is `Y` if ... " then if something isnt an `X` it isnt `Y`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Try to test my code when `I` have a default member initializer. It successed (i.e the default ctor will not defined as deleted) which means the bullet (2.4) is applied **even though** `I` is of non-class type

Comment: (2.4) requires the member to have no brace-or-equal-initializer . If it has an initializer then it doesnt matter if it is const default constructible

Comment: because the quote says "A class type T is const-default-constructible if ..." when it is not a class type then this does not apply, hence a non-class type is not const-default-constructible. Anyhow, sorry for bothering you. I think I understood what the question is about and what caused your confusion. I shouldn't add more confusion ;) The answers explain it quite well

Comment: I am not a language lawyer (neither a native speaker). My naive interpretation of how to read it is best explained by an analogy: "A fruit is a banana if it is yellow and ..." -> My bycicle is not a banana even though it is yellow (and even though ... might apply as well)

Comment: btw if the answers helped you should consider accepting one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the type of S::I said to be non-const-default-constructible?

Yes.  Like you've quoted in [dcl.init]/7 only class types can be *const-default-constructible*.  The reason for this is non-class types do not have a default constructor, meaning they have no default value that can be used if they are declared like

```
const T foo;
```

When you read

> any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* is not *const-default-constructible* ([dcl.init])

It is saying that if you have a member in the form of `const T name;` in your class then the default constructor is deleted if `T` is not *const-default-constructible*.  In your case that means your constructor is deleted because `const int` is not *const-default-constructible*.

---

In the case of `X`, `M` is still not *const-default-constructible* because it is not a class type.  `X` though is *const-default-constructible* because `M` has a *brace-or-equal-initializer* so [class.default.ctor]/2.4 does not apply.

---

This can be boiled down into a simple rule: All const objects must have an initializer

Since built in types do not get default initialized they must have a value provided by the programmer.

Comment: @John Like I said in my answer, only class types can be const-default-constructible.  `M` doesn't have a class type so it isn't const-default-constructible.  That doesn't mean `X` isn't, because you've provded a value for `M`.  You no longer have `const T foo;`, but `const T foo = value;` which is what you need if `T` is not const-default-constructible

Comment: So the term _"const-default-constructible"_ is applied only for class types. So the bullet (2.4) isn't applied because the member M has `brace-or-equal-initializer`. Right? Please add clarification for this in your answer: Does, in such a case, (2.4) apply?

Comment: @John Yes, because `M` has a *brace-or-equal-initializer* section 2.4 does not apply and your class (`X`) is *const-default-constructible*

Comment: After thinking a little bit and rereading the quotes and the answer, I concluded something and I need to know whether it is correct or not. I concluded that "The fact that some type `T` is not a class type, makes `T` non-const-default-constructible type." Is what I conclude correct?

Comment: @John Yes, **only class types** can be *const-default-constructible*

Comment: Thanks. But also class types can be non-const-default-constructible if the conditions defined in [dcl.init]/7 are not met. Right?

Comment: @John Yes, if they do not meet the requirements then they will not be *const-default-constructible*. The first requirement is that `T` needs to be a class type, so if you do not have a class type you are guarantee that it is not *const-default-constructible*

Answer (score 4):

Non-class types are never *const-default-constructible* as you have read correctly.

But I don't think there is any wording missing. It seems intentional. The whole point of *const-default-constructible* is to make sure that you can't accidentally leave an object with an indeterminate value after initialization when you can't change that object's value later.

It would be UB to try to change the value of `I` after initialization (because it is declared `const`), but with the defaulted default constructor or without an explicit initializer on `I`, it would be default-initialized to an indeterminate value (because that is the effect of default-initialization on non-class types) which then is impossible to change. An indeterminate value can be used for almost nothing. The standard doesn't even allow copying it (except for types `unsigned char` and `std::byte`).

So there is no reason to allow you to default-construct this `S` with the defaulted default constructor.

(Technically the standard now allows using placement-`new` to replace the `I` object transparently as long as it is not part of a const-complete object, which allows changing its value in some sense, but that shouldn't be a normal use case.)